# Parameterized validations in the model with clean architecture

Tags: java, validation, clean-architecture, hexagonal-architecture

I am developing an application trying to follow the advice of hexagonal architecture and clean architecture. Dividing the application into layers: infrastructure, application, and model. All this keeping an eye on my imported packages and that there are only dependencies with the framework in the infrastructure layer.

The doubt has come with the implementation in the models. Most of the time if you validate maximum sizes of strings or maximum values and numbers you can use constants and if the condition is not met in the constructor then an exception is thrown:

```
@Value
public class UserName {

    String value;

    public UserName(String value) {
        validate(value);
        this.value = value;
    }

    private void validate(String value) {
        if (value.length() > 100) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is if I want to parameterize these maximum values ​​of the validations or in a properties or database file, for example. The mechanism would be coupled to the way of loading that data that the application framework uses. When should it be validated?

Loading the value in the use case (application layer) through a property service. For example:

```
public class CreateUser() {

    private PropertiesService propertiesService;

    public User create(String nameValue) {
        UserName userName = new UserName(nameValue, propertiesService.getMaxNameLegth());
        //...
        
    }
}

@Value
public class UserName {

    String value;

    public UserName(String value, int maxValue) {
        validate(value);
        this.value = value;
    }

    private void validate(String value) {
        if (value.length() > maxValue) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Or creating a validator to which the class is passed and all its attributes are validated:

```
@Value
public class UserName {

    String value;

    public UserName(String value, int maxValue) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public interface UserNameValidator {
    void validate(UserName userName);
}

public class UserNameValidatorImpl {

    private PropertiesService propertiesService;

    public void validate(UserName userName); {
        if (userName.getValue().length() > propertiesService.getMaxNameLegth()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        
        // validate all atributes
    }
}

public class CreateUser() {

    private UserNameValidator userNameValidator;

    public User create(String nameValue) {
        UserName userName = new UserName(nameValue);
        userNameValidator.validate(userName);
        //...
        
    }
}
```

What is the best solution? the cleanest? Other better possibilities? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The doubt has come with the implementation in the models. Most of the time if you validate maximum sizes of strings or maximum values and numbers you can use constants and if the condition is not met in the constructor then an exception is thrown:

Do you validate the name's length because of domain rules or either because of database constraints like the column length?

Maybe the validation belongs to the database layer and not the domain layer.

> Loading the value in the use case (application layer) through a property service.
> ... or ...
> creating a validator to which the class is passed and all its attributes are validated

If the validation rules are domain rules and they should be loaded at runtime, they should be handled like any other persistent data.

```
+----------------+           +----------------+                  +-----------------------+
|      User      |  -------> | UserValidation |     <---------   | ValidationRepository  |
+----------------+           +----------------+                  +-----------------------+
                                                                            ^
                                                                            |
============================================================================|=============
                                                                            |
                                                                 +----------+------+ 
                                                                 |                 |
                                                            +------------+     +--------+
                                                            | Properties |     |   DB   |
                                                            +------------+     +--------+
```

Pass the `ValidationRepository` to your `CreateUser`

```
public class CreateUser {

    private ValidationRepository validationRepository;

    public User create(String nameValue) {
        UserValidation userValidation = validationRepository.getUserValidation();
        UserName userName = new UserName(nameValue, userValidation);
        //...
        
    }
}
```

When a `User` should be created you can get the `UserValidation` from the `ValidationRepository` and pass it to the `User` or `UserName`.

```
public class UserValidation {

    // should be set (or passed as constructor arg) by the repository implementation
    private int useNameMaxValue;

    public String validateUserName(String userName){
        if (userName.length() > maxValue) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

}
```

The `User` or `UserName` just uses the `UserValidator`.

```
public class UserName {

    String value;

    UserName(String value, UserValidator validator) {
        this.value = validator.validateUserName(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand the proposal and if the validation depends on the business logic or the size of the columns in bbdd. The case of the size of the name was an example. Take for example, the case of validating the user's age, in this case it is business logic, the same example that you have proposed could be applied.